# Using Rasterio to create mask from osmnx graph edges creates black .tif

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio, gdal-rasterize, osmnx

I am using rasterio to create a mask of some .tif with an edge graph that I created with osmnx.
I'm assuming that there is something I have to do to the graph to make it work correctly as it works with geojson files I do have.
Unfortunately they look the same to me.

to reproduce you'll need to import geopandas, rasterio, osmnx and utm.

imports:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import rasterio
import osmnx as ox
import geopandas as gpd
import utm
```

This works:

```
ds = rasterio.open('sn1.tif')
geojson = gpd.read_file('sn1.geojson')
inGDF = geojson

# set a few columns that we will need later
inGDF['type'] = inGDF['road_type'].values
inGDF['class'] = 'highway'
inGDF['highway'] = 'highway'
tmpGDF = ox.project_gdf(inGDF)
gdf_utm_buffer = tmpGDF

    # perform Buffer to produce polygons from Line Segments
gdf_utm_buffer['geometry'] = tmpGDF.buffer(2, 6)
out, _ = mask(ds,
              gdf_utm_buffer.to_crs(geojson.crs).geometry,
              invert=False, nodata = 0, filled = True, pad = True, all_touched = True)
```

but this doesn't

```
ds = rasterio.open('bigtif.tif')
north, south, east, west = get_latlonbox(ds)
graph = ox.graph.graph_from_bbox(north, south, east, west)
gdf_nodes, gdf_edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph,
                                        nodes=True,
                                        edges=True,
                                        node_geometry=True,
                                        fill_edge_geometry=True)

inGDF = gdf_edges

# set a few columns that we will need later
inGDF['type'] = inGDF['highway'].values
inGDF['class'] = 'highway'
inGDF['highway'] = 'highway'
tmpGDF = ox.project_gdf(inGDF)
gdf_utm_buffer = tmpGDF

    # perform Buffer to produce polygons from Line Segments
gdf_utm_buffer['geometry'] = tmpGDF.buffer(2, 6)
out, _ = mask(ds,
              gdf_utm_buffer.to_crs(gdf_edges.crs).geometry,
              invert=False, nodata = 0, filled = True, pad = True, all_touched = True)
```

I also tried to convert the gdf_edges gdf to geojson but that didn't help the result is the same.

The files I'm using you can find [`here`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HJflDUl0Z_mjEuf-qnK_DIiV_H9uzPbE/view?usp=sharing)

`get_latlonbox` is a function I made that takes a rasterio dataset to convert to latitude longtitude with `utm`

```
def get_latlonbox(image_data):
  #rasterio returns bounds in that order, our data is in UTM
    west, south, east, north = image_data.bounds
  #this is how we transform utm to latitude longtitude for osmnx
  #arguments needed are easting (x direction), and northing, northern false sets hemisphere
    north, east = utm.to_latlon(east, north, 37, northern = False)
    south, west = utm.to_latlon(west, south, 37, northern = False)
    return north, south, east, west
```